Grease Pencil still showing in complete darkness
I want to make an animation which would be from bright to dark, and combining 3d and 2d(grease pencil) and when the light goes out grease pencil object can still be seen, and i dont want that, i want it to be complete dark, is there a way for this?
i tried using image as a plane to test if it the 2d problem, but the image works fine with the light and it become dark as expected, is it grease pencil problem, or rendering problem?
rendered using eevee

I have figured it out:
World Properties > Viewport Display and just drag the color all the way to black.
